# Python Scrape Images From CSS Class

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've looked at a couple of solutions for this in Python including lxml, BeautifulSoup, and Scrapy.

The URL is: https://uk.eurosport.yahoo.com/football/players/hugo-lloris/

```html
<div class="player-image soccer-jersey" id="yui_3_16_0_1_1418920336731_663">
            
  <img src="https://s1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/tJcByeD1uUzpRu9blmsOZA--  /YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTE3MDtxPTc1O3c9MTgw/http://l.yimg.com/j/assets/i/us/sp/v/soccer/worldcup/players/374980.1.jpg" width="180" height="170" alt="H. Lloris" title="" class="photo" id="yui_3_16_0_1_1418920336731_664">

</div>
```

We have a div class of "player-image soccer-jersey", then an img inside that, class "photo".

I'd like to download that image (NB: I will go on and download several). I've looked into both *csselector* and *xpath* (not always supported, e.g. the latter with BeautifulSoup) -  yet I just can't seem to download it and in examples I've found people access the img's  tag to obtain the URL's *href*, which is not the case here.

Comment: were any of the answers helpful to you? this community functions via two-way feedback between askers and answerers. you should upvote or select (click the green check) any responses that worked for you.

Comment: @MagentaNova I don't have the reputation to upvote, but I've clicked the colourless tick. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you already have a running python environment with all of the necessary dependencies installed for this code.

On a command line interface, create a Scrapy project:

```
scrapy startproject yuiImage
```

That will create a ***yuiImage*** project folder inside your current directory.

Then, create a ***yuiimage_spider.py*** file inside the ***yuiImage/spiders*** folder that resides within your project folder:

```
import re, scrapy
from urllib import urlretrieve

class YuiimageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yuiimage"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://uk.eurosport.yahoo.com/football/players/hugo-lloris/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        imageSrcs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'player-image') and contains(@class, 'soccer-jersey')]/img[@style and contains(@style, 'yimg.com') and contains(@class, 'photo')]/@style").extract()
        for src in imageSrcs:
            imgUrl = re.search('http\:.*', re.search('[^(].*\(\'(.*)\'\);', src).group(1)).group(0)
            urlretrieve(imgUrl, imgUrl.split("/").pop())
```

Then run the following command inside your project folder:

```
scrapy crawl yuiimage
```

That should download every image complying with your specified rules inside your project folder.

Cheers.

Comment: This is the best solution because using the xpath makes things more flexible for when I want to scrape other images, which you logically foresaw me wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to download an image is using urllib's [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) method. it takes an optional filename parameter, wherein you can specify the path and name for the downloaded file (by default, i believe it autogenerates a name and puts it in the current directory).

for your html snippet, you can do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from urllib import urlretrieve

soup = BS(**the html you scraped**) 
imgTag = soup.find('img',id='yui_3_16_0_1_1418920336731_664')
imgSrc = imgTag['src'] # in this case, the source is the full url
# but in other cases it may be relative path, in which case you would append it
# to the base url
urlretrieve(imgSrc,filename=**path that you want to save the image to**)
```

Comment: if i get your meaning, @djdavies7, it's inflexible because it treats the 'src' attribute as a full url? you can use the urljoin method from url parse, with the base url and src path as the two arguments, to get the full url for urlretrieve.

Comment: You worked on the specific ID rather than the CSS class which is the same across all of the URLs, so getting the next ID (I said I'd scrape several) would be troublesome. Cheers.